# Performance of Spring @Autowire vs getBean(className)

Tags: java, spring, performance, autowired

There are two variants of code:

```
public class MyClass {
 public void myMethod() {
  AnotherClass object = SpringContexHolder.getContext().getBean(AnotherClass.class);
  object.doSomething();
 }
}

@Component
public class MyClass {
@Autowired
AnotherClass object;     

public void myMethod() {
 object.doSomething();
}
}
```

Will there be any performance penalties in the first variant (by the way in the first place it's not spring bean, just simple class)?
Does Autowiring do the same as getBean?

P.S. I think I should expand my question a little. The situation is that team I joined uses Spring injection in the project only via getBean(className). The reason I guess is that most of project classes already written are not Spring beans and using autowiring in one class means usually making dependent class bean as well and so on until most of the classes become beans...

Ok, I think I understand testability penalties and overall lacking of code-style of such an approach. But isn't there a perfomance penalty alsо? Isn't there difference between performance of ready-to-go Spring singleton that is constructed on startup with all it's fields autowired and invoking getBean(classname) (afaik several times slower then pure hashmap.get(object)) from non-spring non-singleton class (ecpecially in critical places)?

P.S.S. I created smth like mini-benchmark (I understand that it's hard to get real info because of work of GC, JIT and so on but nevertheless...).
My results are (the bigger numbers - the worse):
Autowiring time - 193, GetBean time - 2161, Method in the same class - 173, Static method in another class - 206

Comment: Always use the second way for readability and testing. Also the first way will fail only when you call `myMethod` when no bean has been found, whereas the second will not even let your application start up properly

Comment: Also you should not really care about performance with spring, as it already has quite an overhead itself and may not be used in performance critical applications

Comment: IMO, you shouldn't really care about the performance of the application at startup. You use autowired because it is more convenient; if you care about startup time then you could avoid using Spring at all- but then the drawback is that you need to do everything manually.

Comment: I do not think 'using spring' is relative to 'you shouldn't really care about the performance'. This question based on using spring, the performance between `getBean` and `@autowired`. I think there are two concept 'dependency lookup' and 'dependency inject'. getBean is dependency lookup. @autowired is dependency inject. This question is good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's going to be inefficient to lookup a bean in the Spring context (which is often composite) every time you need to access it. You're essentially looking up an item in multiple hash tables multiple times, thrashing the CPU cache, wasting time and potentially preventing other optimization like inlining due to a more complex execution path.

Definitely use autowiring (annotation-based or constructor-based). That way the lookup is done once at application startup, and after that the class is accessed via a direct reference.

Testability is perfectly fine even with the `@Autowired` annotation. You simply autowire mocks instead of actual objects. Also look into [Mockito](https://dzone.com/articles/use-mockito-mock-autowired) and [Spring-Test](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#integration-testing-annotations-spring) annotations to inject mocks and otherwise augment the Spring context for testing purposes.

Comment: Spring-Test is actually for intégration testing, it is a real pain to do unit testing with it. Using constructor to inject object allow you to made unit tests by injecting mocks (from mockito for exemple) without all the spring boilerplate.

Comment: I usually have no problems with Spring-mock when disabling classpath scanning and providing mocks for all dependencies. But Mockito is definitely useful, too.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you shouldn't use any of this. As some users already mentionned in comments, you shouldn't take care of performances. But for testability, use constructor based injection (and the @Autowired is implicit) :

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

  private final AnotherClass object;     

  public MyClass(AnotherClass object) {
    this.object = object;
  }
}
```